# Custom "navigate up" behavior for certain fragment using Navigation component

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-architecture-navigation

I want to add custom *up navigation* from fragment using Navigation component

In my `build.gradle(app)` I use `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha04` dependency to have access to `onBackPressedDispatcher` from activity.

So I implemented `OnBackPressedCallback` in my fragment and
registered callback to dispatcher:

```
requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this)
```

I expected that pressing *navigate up* in toolbar will call it, but it doesn't. 
Pressing device's back button calls it as expected.

Is there a similar way to add some callback in fragment on navigate up action?

**UPDATE**

overridden methods `onOptionsItemSelected` and `onSupportNavigateUp` doesn't invoked on pressing *up button* in toolbar

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I found a solution

`handleOnBackPressed()` method invokes only on device's back button click.
I wonder, why neither `onOptionsItemSelected()` nor `onSupportNavigateUp()` methods haven't been called on pressing "up button" in toolbar. And the answer is I used

```
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(toolbar, navController, appBarConfiguration)
```

in activity to setup toolbar with navigation component.
And that made toolbar responsive for work with navigation internally, pressing "up button" haven't invoked any of overridden methods in activity or fragments.

Instead should be used

```
NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration)
```

That will make actionBar responsive for navigation, thus I can use overridden functions `onOptionsItemSelected()` and `onSupportNavigateUp()`
And best place (in my case) to add custom behavior on "up button" click for certain screen is

```
onSupportNavigateUp()
```

of hosted activity, like that

```
override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = this.findNavController(R.id.mainNavHostFragment)
        return when(navController.currentDestination?.id) {
            R.id.destinationOfInterest -> {
                // custom behavior here 
                true
            }
            else -> navController.navigateUp()
        }
}
```

But worth to say, that if you want implement custom behavior directly in fragment, answer of @Enzokie should work like a charm

Comment: Does this have to be set up in an Activity, or can it be in a Fragment?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky You  can call activty's `onBackPressed()` from `onSupportNavigateUp()` and it will get override in fragment's `onBackPressedDispatcher()`.

Answer (score 9):

You need to call `onBackPressed()` from `onBackPressedDispatcher` property. Assuming your Toolbar is properly setup you can use the code below in your Activity.

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem : MenuItem?) : Boolean {
    if (menuItem.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()
        return true // must return true to consume it here

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem)
}
```

on Fragment override

```
override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)            

        //enable menu
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)

        requireActivity()
                .onBackPressedDispatcher
                .addCallback(this){
                   //true means that the callback is enabled
                    this.isEnabled = true
                    exitDialog() //dialog to conform exit
                }
    }
```

What this does is :

> Trigger a call to the currently added OnBackPressedCallback
>   callbacks in reverse order in which they were added. Only if the most 
>   **false** from its `OnBackPressedCallback#handleOnBackPressed()`
>   will any previously added callback be called.

I am using AndroidX in my example therefore my import will look like

`import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but thing is onOptionsItemSelected method doesn't invoke when I press "up button". But it does when I select another menu item in toolbar.
Tried both in fragment and in activity

Comment: Can you temporarily replace  `onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()` with a log message? Let me know if it is called.

Comment: Sure I logged onOptionsItemSelected and it doesn't call.
Seems like Navigation component handling "up navigation" event internally.
What else worth to mention, that onSupportNavigateUp method also doesn't invoke in Activity

Comment: FYI onBackPressedDispatcher doesn't have onBackPressed() method,
call handleOnBackPressed()  method from OnBackPressedCallback interface

Comment: `getOnBackPressedDispatcher()` returns `OnBackPressedDispatcher` (in kotlin it is `onBackPressedDispatcher` property) and it has a public method called `onBackPressed()`. The `handleOnBackPressed()` must not be called explicitly because it defeats the purpose of having an interface. Btw this is from `androix.activity`.

Comment: @RokoSpark you can view the actual framework source [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/a5a22718f4d920df72666da8fe2325cfee0bedd7/activity/src/main/java/androidx/activity/OnBackPressedDispatcher.java#131) for `OnBackPressedDispatcher`.

Comment: This wasn't working for me, because the `onOptionsItemSelected` wasn't been called. To fix that you need to call `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` in onCreate in your fragment

Answer (score 6):

This set up also works and you won't need to override `onSupportNavigateUp` in your activity:

```
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(toolbar, navController, appBarConfiguration)
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener {
    if (navController.currentDestination?.id == R.id.destinationOfInterest) {
        // Custom behavior here
    } else {
        NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, configuration)
    }
}
```

I prefer to set up the `Toolbar` since it will handle automatically the up navigation and open/close a `DrawerLayout` if you have one.

Comment: This opens a way to `        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener {
            onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()
        }` - was really helpful in my case, thanks.

Comment: @Juan @ror a combination of your answers worked. Thanks. Docs says there should be a call to `onBackPressedDispatcher.hasEnabledCallbacks()` before calling `onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed() `

Answer (score 0):

I've done it using this in the Fragment alone:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    val menuProvider = object : MenuProvider {
        override fun onCreateMenu(menu: Menu, menuInflater: MenuInflater) {
        }

        override fun onMenuItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {
            if (menuItem.itemId == android.R.id.home)
            ...
        }
     }

    lifecycle.addObserver(object : DefaultLifecycleObserver {
        override fun onResume(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
            super.onResume(owner) 
            activity!!.addMenuProvider(menuProvider)
        }

        override fun onPause(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
            super.onPause(owner) 
            activity!!.removeMenuProvider(menuProvider)
        }
    })
}
```

Also requested to have it here:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/273299805

Answer (score -1):

Add click event to toolbar back button in this way

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
 switch (item.getItemId()) {
case android.R.id.home:
    // Toolbar back button pressed, do something you want    

default:
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
}
```

Another way

```
  Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    // Title and subtitle
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Toolbar back button pressed, do something you want    
        }
    });
```

Comment: And if it doesn't work in fragment, and you want to pass that event to fragment from activity, in your activity you must have fragment object when you initialized it, so you can write a method in your fragment, and can call when back button from activity.

Comment: Hi thanks for reply, I don't know why but onOptionsItemSelected method doesn't invokes when I click "up button" neither in fragment nor in activity; clicking another options menu invokes it as expected.
I also came up with your another way, but this click listener became global for every screen and not just for specific screen (fragment)

Answer (score -1):

I customized **(directly in Fragment)** the backbress on Toolbar by using the following steps:

**1. onCreate [Activity]:**

`NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration)`

**2. onSupportNavigateUp [Activity]:**

```
override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()
        return super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
```

**3. Customize or disable backpress [Fragment]:**

```
requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(viewLifecycleOwner) {
           isEnabled = false
           // enable or disable the backpress
       }
```

Comment: Navigate up should NOT do the same as pressing back. This is therefore a bad solution. Source: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-principles#the_up_button_never_exits_your_app